# Speed Up Ember Rendering - List of Ember Computed Properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ember.js, ember-data

I've been trying to figure out a way to speed up rendering when changing the dependencies of a computed property on a larger dataset.

Example here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/IKicoBa/1/edit

You'll notice that there is approx. 3-5 seconds of delay when enabling and disabling a row. I've tested the filtering mixin and the name sorting and they seem to compute almost instantaneously. It seems to be an issue with rendering the DOM changes.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need to loop twice through your data, I mean, you already have an if in this code:

```
{{#each obj in sortedObservations itemController='observationContainer'}}
<div class='observation-container row'>
    {{#if isActive}}
        <div {{action 'disable'}} class='toggleActive'>Deactivate</div>
    {{else}}
        <div {{action 'enable'}} class='toggleActive'>Activate</div>
    {{/if}}
    <div class='observation-participant-name'>{{obj.participant.first_name}}</div>
```

so, if you already have an if to differentiate between the active and inactive ones, why looping twice ? so, just change your loop to loop through all your sorted data(which I think is sortedObservations), and that's it, you can also remove the active/inactive Observations properties, that will improve the performance too.

Comment: if you want to show the inactive ones last, then change the sort to sort function.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. I'll try that out, although when I tested I didn't see any improvements when just completely removing the inactive list, filter, etc. I'm a bit confused at your last comment, change the sort to sort function? Do you mean, sort the inactive ones in my sortedObservations property?

Comment: right, I mean, you need the inactive ones at the bottom of the list, right ? then sort them too. I removed the second loop, the one that loops through the inactive list, then, I changed the first loop to loop through all your list, and that improved a lot the performance.

Comment: Would you mind linking me to the JSBin? I'm not seeing a way to use the mixin to do the filtering.